# Tableau calculated field summing up the values

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have a table like this

```
 ----------------------------------------------
    ID  Name            Value                    |
    ---------------------------------------------|          
    1   Bob             4                        |
    2   Mary            3                        |
    3   Bob             5                        |
    4   Jane            3                        |
    5   Jane            1                        |
    ----------------------------------------------
```

Is there any ways to do out a calculated field where if the name is "Bob" , it'll sum up all the values that have the name "Bob"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If Name = “Bob” then Value end
```